# include prevents other layout to be shown

Tags: android

I have a layout which starts with an include to another layout and right after that there is a LinearLayout with two buttons in it.

The problem is that I don't see the layout with the two buttons after I added the include. But when I wrap the include with another layout, I do see the two buttons below the include and the problem is solved.

Can someone please tell me why I have to wrap the include?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/keypad_layout"
            layout="@layout/keypad_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAudio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_audio_selector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_video_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keypad_layout"
            layout="@layout/keypad_layout" />
```

perhaps the `layout_height` in `keypad_layout` root is `match_parent` so override it in the include

Comment: You are right, I forgot layout_height in the keypad_layout as match_parent. Thanks!